# Font not showing in China

Tags: css, magento, fonts, font-face

I am in the US and I recently completed a Magento website. The entire website is using the Myriad Pro font and I've loaded it to the site using @font-face.

My client (in China) is saying the font is not loading properly. He is viewing it as Times Roman. I've tried it on several computers in the US and it seems to be loading just fine.  This is how I have it coded in the CSS:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: Myriad Pro;
src: url(../font/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.OTF);
}
```

Any recommendations / solutions / or reasons why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: i which browser you & client have test this? Your website is in cross domain?

Comment: Is the user able to access the font URL? What do they get when thry hit the complete path of `../font/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.OTF`?

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR IE and Chrome

Comment: Everyone in China is still using IE6, so you might want to test using it.

Comment: Nivas didn't ask what the URL is, he asked you if the people in China are able to access this URL at all.

Comment: @CreativeMind my mistake.  China IP is blocked so the sites accessing the page are allowed on the .htaccess.  They are able to access the URL

Answer (score 0):

If you load you site in IE you can see the error in the console, like

> CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check.
>   Permission must be Installable. File: MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.OTF

So goto this [**site**](http://everythingfonts.com/font-face) upload your font, now you will get the one rar file. extract and upload in your server.

And change your css like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadProRegular';
    src: url('myriadpro-regular.eot');
    src: url('myriadpro-regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('myriadpro-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('myriadpro-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('myriadpro-regular.svg#MyriadProRegular') format('svg');
}
```

Let me know if this work or not.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the comments above I think I have a solution for you. My clients are based all over the world and we have very similar problems on a daily basis.

The funny thing is that it is a very very simple fix. When you first show your client your site/page it downloads the stylesheet into the cache.

The above is the problem, just ask her to complete a hard refresh and see if that works,

Usually works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used font format like `.eot` and `. ttf` true type format? Don't know the reason why you using only `.otf` format.   Ideally custom fonts are called by this way for cross browser.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to support older IE versions. IE6 has a large market share in China. Today IE6 + Qihoo 360( a safe IE6) have a marketshare of over 40%.